# Expanded standard deviation in logarithmic scale

Tags: rf, measurement, emc

Hello and good day to all.

Referring to picture attached I have a question.

[image].

I am working on different measurements and trying to find the mean and standard deviation values of these measurements. The values are given in dBuV/m so for calculating different values I have first converted them to linear scale and applied the formualas of mean and standard deviation. My problem is till calculating mean or avg value I am getting the as expected result **"When I converted these linear values back to Logarithmic scale".** But for standard deviation I am not getting the correct value when I converted it back to dBuV/m scale. The standard deviation after the measurement values shouldnt be more than 1-3 dB but strangely I am getting **"70 dBuV/m**. Do anybody has any idea where is the problem. Here below I am pasting all the formulas i have used so far.

1. From dBuV/m to linear scale \$=\dfrac{10^{value/20}}{1,000,000}\$
2. For calculating power average \$=
   \sqrt{\dfrac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2.....x_{10}^2}{10}}\$
3. For standard deviation \$= \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum{(A(i)-Avg)^2}}{9}}\$
4. For expanded S.D I multiplied S.D with **2.228** to get 95 % of confidence level of guassian distribution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an electrical design question.

Comment: While this is indeed a mathematical problem, the unit __dBu__  and its mathematical implications belongs more to electronics than math. (I guess on math.se you have to explan first, what dBu means). So __I'm against closing__.

Answer (score 3):

It's a mathematical problem.

Let's look at a simple example and say you have a sample with mean \$\bar{x}=100\$ and \$\sigma=10\$.

If you convert each value separately, you get

\$\log_{10}(\bar{x})=\log_{10}100=2\$
 \$\log_{10}(\sigma)=\log_{10}10=1\$

So, is the result really \$2\pm 1\$ ???

Standard deviation means that 68% of all values are within \$[\bar{x}-\sigma;\bar{x}+\sigma]=[90;110]\$

Taking logarithm of this gives \$[\log_{10}{90};\log_{10}{110}]=[1.95;2.04]=[2-0.05;2+0.04]\$

---

Back to your values:

\$\bar{x}=0.01807\$ and \$\sigma=0.0011435\$

Converting back to dBu with \$D(x)\$ being the inverse of the formula of point 1. of your question:

\$D(\bar{x})=85.139\$
\$D(\sigma)=61.165\$   <- this is not he value you are searching for!

BUT:

\$D(\bar{x}-\sigma)=84.571\$
\$D(\bar{x}+\sigma)=85.672\$

So, the interval where 68% of all values reside, has a width of just 1.1.

You can't just convert \$\sigma\$ alone to dBu, you have to do it for \$\bar{x}\pm\sigma\$.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a diagram showing what's going on. (Here, I used your exact values. Above values may differ due to rounding)

[image]

The violet curve shows your gauss-shaped noise distribution: Linear scale on the x-axis, log scale (dBu) on the y-axis.
The bright green and blue stripes indicate the 68% and 95% interval.
The red curve is \$D(x)\$.

In theory, you have to do the conversion for \$\bar{x}\pm 2.228\sigma\$ to get the upper / lower boundary of the 95% interval in dBu. However, the width of this interval is *roughly* about 2.228 times the width of the 68% interval, because the conversion function is *almost* linear in that range. As counterexample, have a look at the green curve!

---

Here is the data. The upper dataset is yours, the lower is for the green curve:

```
          |      Value      |    Diff to x     |
          | linear  | dBu   |  linear  |  dBu  |
..........|.........|.......|..........|.......|
x         | 0.01807 | 85.14 |          |       |
x+s       | 0.01951 | 85.80 |  0.00143 |  0.66 |
x-s       | 0.01664 | 84.42 |  0.00143 |  0.72 |
x+2.228s  | 0.02127 | 86.56 |  0.00320 |  1.41 |
x-2.228s  | 0.01488 | 83.45 |  0.00320 |  1.69 |
..........|.........|.......|..........|.......|
x         | 0.00500 | 73.98 |          |       |
x+s       | 0.00700 | 76.90 |  0.00200 |  2.92 |
x-s       | 0.00300 | 69.54 |  0.00200 |  4.44 |
x+2.228s  | 0.00946 | 79.51 |  0.00446 |  5.53 |
x-2.228s  | 0.00054 | 54.71 |  0.00446 | 19.27 |
```

Comment: Well thats make sense. Thank you so much for such a good explaination.

Comment: Well there is still one conceptual thing I am missing. If I follow your above method then I dont need to adjust my S.D value according to student distribution. Because If I use the expanded S.D value then I get the much higher width i.e. 3.11 in this case. So what can I deduce from it that after using the expanded S.D I am getting the 95 % of confidence interval instead of 68 % by using the x¯±σ. ?

Comment: Your comment is a bit unclear to me. However, I've added something to my answer which - I hope - makes everything clear to you.